# Cancellation law of congruence and gcd.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

How $$ax ≡ ay\ (mod\ n)$$

==>
 $$x ≡ y\ (mod\ \frac{\ n}{gcd(a,n)})$$

How we got gcd here?
Please assume I know nothing about ring theory.

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for gcd and mod using `\gcd` and `\bmod`, respectively. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. There's also a command `\pmod` as in `ax\equiv ay\pmod n`, yielding $ax\equiv ay\pmod n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write $ax\equiv ay\pmod n$ as $ax-ay=kn$ with integer $k$. Thus $a(x-y)=kn$. Now divide by $\gcd(a,n)$ to obtain

$$
\frac a{\gcd(a,n)}(x-y)=k\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}\;.
$$

Since $\frac a{\gcd(a,n)}$ has no factors in common with $\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}$, it must divide $k$, so

$$
x-y=\frac{k\gcd(a,n)}a\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}\;.
$$

This is

$$
x-y=k'\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}
$$

with integer $k'$, so

$$
x\equiv y\,\left(\operatorname{mod}{\frac n{\gcd(a,n)}}\right)\;.
$$

Comment: This is a very simple and thorough explanation. Thanks!